# Gem strong parameters não instalada

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estou tendo problemas para add uma gem no meu projeto, a gem strong parameters. A minha versão do ruby on rails eh 4.1.4. Não sei o que esta acontecendo.

Quando eu dou o bundle install
 [image: eis o que parace no meu terminal com bundle install]

Quando eu dou um bundle update aparece isso

[image: eis o que aparece no meu terminal com bundle update]

Answer (score 1):

Na [página oficial da *gem* strong_parameters no GitHub](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) diz o seguinte:

> This plugin is only fully compatible with Rails versions 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2 but not 4.0+, as it is part of Rails Core in 4.0. An unofficial Rails 2 version is strong_parameters_rails2.

Que traduzido significa:

> Esse plugin é apenas totalmente compatível com as versões 3.0, 3.1 e 3.2 do Rails, mas não com as versões a partir da 4.0, já que a partir da versão 4.0 essa *gem* já foi integrada em seu *core*. Uma versão não oficial para Rails 2 é a strong_parameters_rails2.

Ou seja, como você está usando a versão 4.1, essa *gem* já está instalada, mesmo que não apareça no Gemfile.